# Named Constructor Dart, with no values

Tags: dart

I was going through some code when I found this snippet:

```
class DBHelper {
  DBHelper._();

  static final DBHelper db = DBHelper._();
  static Database _database;

  Future<Database> get database async {
    if (_database == null) {
      _database = await initDB();
    }
    return _database;
  }
}
```

Can anyone simplify this definition of Named Constructor?
Also can there be any alternative way of achieving this functionality.

Comment: Please do no post code as image. That makes it impossible to look up in search engines, impossible to read for screen readers and is super inconvenient even to those just looking at it here.

Comment: What exactly do you want simplified? What requirements do you have? It's a lot simpler if you just delete it, but I guess you still need parts of it?

Comment: By only having `DBHelper._();` as the constructor, you prevent code from outside your library to create an instance of `DBHelper` since all variables, methods and constructors with `_` as named prefix, are considered private in Dart. So with this design, you are making sure that all users of this class needs to use the static variable `db` to get an instance which makes your class a singleton.

Comment: @nvoigt I'm really sorry but I didn't have privileges to post the image
I'll try using the markdown next time